# Android: How to click button inside frame layout after zooming

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building my first android project/first java project. I am trying to draw an image with multiple buttons over the top of it that the user can click on. However after zooming in the button enlarges as i had hoped and maintains its relative position with the image in the background, but it no longer responds to the onClickListener.

XML Code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/DeckLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <!-- <CustomDrawableView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              />  -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/deck12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/QM2_12002"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/zoom_in" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
package com.sgs.hotelguru;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MapsExample extends Activity {

    View mainView = null;
    final float Zoom_max = 5f;
    private static final String TAG = "Die Karte";

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_example);
      mainView =findViewById(R.id.DeckLayout);

      //Button buttonZoomOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zoom_out);
      //Button buttonNormal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
      Button buttonZoomIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zoom_in);

      /*buttonZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        zoom(0.5f,0.5f,new PointF(0,0));    
       }
      });
      buttonNormal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        zoom(1f,1f,new PointF(0,0));  
       }
      });*/
      buttonZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        zoom(new PointF(0,0));   
       }
      });
      mainView.post(new Runnable() {
          // Post in the parent's message queue to make sure the parent
          // lays out its children before you call getHitRect()
          @Override
          public void run() {
              // The bounds for the delegate view (an ImageButton
              // in this example)
              Button QM2_12002 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QM2_12002);
              QM2_12002.setX(300);
              QM2_12002.setY(400);
              QM2_12002.setEnabled(true);
              QM2_12002.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      Toast.makeText(MapsExample.this, 
                              "YOU CLICKY THE BUTTON YAY!", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

          }
      });
  }


     /** zooming is done from here */
     public void zoom(PointF pivot){
      mainView.setPivotX(pivot.x);
      mainView.setPivotY(pivot.y);  
      float workScaleX = mainView.getScaleX();
      float workScaleY = mainView.getScaleY();
      if(workScaleX<Zoom_max)
      {
      mainView.setScaleX(workScaleX+1f);
      mainView.setScaleY(workScaleY+1f);  
      }
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    View mainView;
    Button QM2_12002;
    Button buttonZoomIn;
    final float Zoom_max = 5f;
    private static final String TAG = "Die Karte";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_example);
        mainView =findViewById(R.id.DeckLayout);

        //Button buttonZoomOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zoom_out);
        //Button buttonNormal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
        buttonZoomIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zoom_in);
        QM2_12002 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QM2_12002);

      /*buttonZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        zoom(0.5f,0.5f,new PointF(0,0));
       }
      });
      buttonNormal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        zoom(1f,1f,new PointF(0,0));
       }
      });*/
        buttonZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                zoom(new PointF(0,0));
            }
        });
        QM2_12002.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "YOU CLICKY THE BUTTON YAY!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mainView.post(new Runnable() {
            // Post in the parent's message queue to make sure the parent
            // lays out its children before you call getHitRect()
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // The bounds for the delegate view (an ImageButton
                // in this example)
                QM2_12002.setX(300);
                QM2_12002.setY(400);
                QM2_12002.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }


    /** zooming is done from here */
    public void zoom(PointF pivot){
        mainView.setPivotX(pivot.x);
        mainView.setPivotY(pivot.y);
        float workScaleX = mainView.getScaleX();
        float workScaleY = mainView.getScaleY();
        if(workScaleX<Zoom_max)
        {
            mainView.setScaleX(workScaleX+1f);
            mainView.setScaleY(workScaleY+1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The button clicks and that debug toast triggers, however nothing triggers when clicking it after zooming in